# Proof of Fixed Point for nonlinear systems in Pazy's Semigroups of linear operators and applications to PDEs book

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, semigroup-of-operators, nonlinear-analysis

In Theorem 1.2 of Pazy's book called Semigroups of linear operators and applications to PDEs, a fixed point method is used to show that the nonlinear problem has a solution. The map $F:C([t_0,T];X) \to C([t_0, T];X)$ is defined by

$$(Fu)(t)=T(t-t_0)u_0 + \int_{t_0}^t T(t-s) f(s,u(s)) ds, t_0 \leq t\leq T.$$

Using the assumption that
$$\|T(r)v\|_X \leq M\|v\|_X$$
for all $r \in [0,T]$ and the fact that $f$ is continuous in $t$ and uniformly Lipshitz continuous with constant $L$ on $X$, Pazy shows
$$\|(Fu)(t)-(Fv)(t)\| \leq ML(t-t_0)\|u-v\|.$$
This part is understandable to me. He then says using this inequality and the definition of $F$ you can show using induction that
$$||(F^nu)(t)-(F^n)v(t)||\leq \frac{(ML(t-t_0))^n}{n!}||u-v||.$$

To me this part is clear without the factorial, but I am not sure how we get the bound divided by $n!$. I'm assuming it has something to do with the properties of $T(t)$ since $T(t)$ is a $C_0$ semigroup, but I still don't see it. Does anyone have any ideas where this came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standard kind of estimate used, for example, in the proof of Picard's existence theorem. In order to get the factorial, you have to use the integral equality:

$$\begin{aligned}
\|(F^2u)(t)-(F^2v)(t)\|&\leq\int_{t_0}^t \|T(t-s) [f(s,(Fu)(s))-f(s,(Fv)(s))] \|\,ds\\
&\leq M \int_{t_0}^t \|f(s,(Fu)(s))-f(s,(Fv)(s)) \|\,ds\\
&\leq M L \int_{t_0}^t \|(Fu)(s)-(Fv)(s) \|\,ds\\
&\leq M L \int_{t_0}^t ML(s-t_0)\|u-v\|\,ds\\
&= M^2 L^2\|u-v\|\int_{t_0}^t (s-t_0)\,ds\\
&= M^2 L^2\|u-v\|\frac{(s-t_0)^2}{2}\Bigg|_{s=t_0}^{s=t}\\
&= \frac{(M L(t-t_0))^2}{2}\|u-v\|\\
\end{aligned}$$

Analogously, the general case is proved by induction.